# Jensen's inequality applied in proof of Theorem 6.2 of Entropy and heat kernel bounds on a Ricci flow background

Tags: partial-differential-equations, ricci-flow

Picture below is from [Entropy and heat kernel bounds on a Ricci flow background](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.07093.pdf). I want to get the red line. For me, the Jensen's inequality is
$$
\varphi\left(\int_\Omega f d\mu\right) \le \int_\Omega \varphi\circ f d\mu
$$
when $\varphi$ is convex. Since $x\rightarrow x\ln x$ is convex, by Jensen's inequality, I have
$$
\ln(\frac{1}{|B|_0}\int_B u d g_{_{_0}})\frac{1}{|B|_0}\int_B u d g_{_{_0}}
=
\ln(\int_B \frac{u}{|B|_0} d g_{_{_0}})\int_B \frac{u}{|B|_0} d g_{_{_0}}
\\
\le 
\int_B  \frac{u}{|B|_0}\ln(\frac{u}{|B|_0}) d g_{_{_0}}
=
\frac{1}{|B|_0}\int_B u(\ln u - \ln|B|_0) dg_{_{_0}}
\tag{1}
$$
since $\int_B u  ~d g_{_{_0}} =1$, it is equal to
$$
\ln(\frac{1}{|B|_0}\int_B u d g_{_{_0}})\frac{1}{|B|_0}\int_B u d g_{_{_0}}
\le 
\frac{1}{|B|_0}\int_B u\ln u dg_{_{_0}} -\frac{\ln|B|_0}{|B|_0}
\tag{2}
$$
Obviously, (2) is not same with the red line of picture below. Whether I make some mistake or there is something imply   $\ln |B|_0 \ge 1$ ?

> [image]

Comment: The author has applied the inequality to the measure $\mu=\frac 1 {\vert B\vert _0} g_0$

Comment: @JackT   Thanks very much.